# Integrating Legacy UI with PRISM

Tags: prism, prism-2

We are currently developing Sliverlight 4.0 based web application using PRISM 4.0 for Sliverlight 4.0. This web UI is a composite application consists of Legacy UI developed by some 3rd party and in-house developed UI.

Can someone suggest how to integrate the Legacy UI in to the Shell? Docuemntation says its possible but doesn't mention about how to do it.

Any Help is appriciated

Thanks

TheITGuy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

I did it for now in very PRISM way. Following steps that I took to slove this proble.

1 - Create a WPF shell appliction as specifed in documentation

2 - Add ContentControl to the shee.xaml

2 - Create a new Module as specified in the documentation

4 - Add web browser control and set the link based on business logic

5 - Load the module in the shell as specified in documentation.

6 - Deploy WPF application with ClickOnce deployment by publishing Shell application on the netwrok folder

I don't know if this is the right way to integrate Legacy WEB UI but it is working.

Any idea or suggestion is wellcome.

Thanks

Prateek